# How do I make an editable paragraph in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm looking for a way to make a `p` tag that can be edited on the HTML page itself.
Basically, it's a paragraph that acts like a text input.
I don't want to use jQuery. And I don't want to have a text input that will edit the paragraph, I want the paragraph itself to be editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**contenteditable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) to make tags like `div`, `span`, `p`, etc. editable by the user.

```html
<span contenteditable>
   Edit this content to add your own.
</span>

 <p contenteditable>
   Click over me to edit.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use with true/false. by default its true.
It supports all the latest version of browsers.

```
<p contenteditable="true">This is an editable paragraph.</p>

Value   Description
true    Specifies that the element is editable
false   Specifies that the element is not editable
```