# HTML input fields as paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a web calculator with 2 fields to take inputs, and I want to change its type to paragraph. How to do so? And how add listeners to support tapping on the paragraphs to make them “active” and indicate this somehow with CSS?

Once the web page gets opened somehow I want to take values from the 2 fields.

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="screen"></div>
  
  <div class="inputs">
    <p id="carbs">Carbs/100g</p>
    <p id="portion">Portion (g)</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="calcul">
    <button id="one">1</button>
    <button id="two">2</button>
    <button id="three">3</button><br>
    <button id="four">4</button>
    <button id="five">5</button>
    <button id="six">6</button><br>
    <button id="seven">7</button>
    <button id="eight">8</button>
    <button id="nine">9</button><br>
    <button id="zero">0</button>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>
    <button id="clear">C</button><br>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    <button id="equals">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to capture input and show it in paragraphs, or actually convert the inputs? What have you tried? Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to make an effort and show us.

Comment: Maybe you want this: [How do I make an editable paragraph in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66529344/how-do-i-make-an-editable-paragraph-in-html)

Answer (score -1):

To change the input fields to paragraphs and add listeners to them, you can do the following:

```js
const carbsField = document.querySelector("#carbs");
const portionField = document.querySelector("#portion");

carbsField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  carbsField.classList.add("active");
  portionField.classList.remove("active");
});

portionField.addEventListener("click", () => {
  portionField.classList.add("active");
  carbsField.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```css
.input-field {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-field.active {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="screen">
  </div>
  
  <div class="inputs">
    <p id="carbs" class="input-field">Carbs/100g: <span id="carbs-value">0</span></p>
    <p id="portion" class="input-field">Portion (g): <span id="portion-value">0</span></p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- rest of the HTML code -->
</div>
```

Comment: There's no ability to accept input here. Regardless, poor-quality questions should not be answered with guesses.